# Create Task in XML/Java Editor

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, task, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

In Eclipse 3.6.2 (SpringSource Tool Suite 2.6.1) when editing a .properties file, I can get a handy "Add Task..." dialog by right-clicking in the margin of the editor.

Is there any way to get this functionality in the Java and XML editors? I can create a new task by other means, by the forms are different, take up more space and are generally a bit of a pain. If there's a keyboard shortcut for the brief Add Task dialogue, that'd be grand!

Answer (score 1):

I see 'Add Task...' in my Java editor when I right-click on the gutter.  Do you not see it?

[image: Add Task... screenshot]

Comment: You're right - it's there in the Java editor, which is great. Any idea how to get it in the XML editor? I've got a lot of tasks relating to Spring config files!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy way of doing this.  One possibility is to create your own plugin to do this (a bit of a pain), another possibility is to raise a bug report on the SpringSource Tool Suite issue tracker and ask that this change be added to the Spring Bean Config editor.  http://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS  (I assume that's where you are editing your spring beans).

Answer (score 1):

Put your cursor on the line where you want the task, and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, in sequence.  A dialog will prompt you for the task description. Same as going to Edit > Add Task.